# Can I invoke the base constructor of a class from calling code?

Tags: c#, constructor

I have two classes, one derived from the other and both have parametrized constructors. I want to call the constructor in both classes when I instantiate the derived class.

So my question is: what is the syntax to pass parameters to both base and derived classes from the calling code?

I tried something like this but it does not compile:

```
DerivedClass derivedclass = new DerivedClass(arguments):base( arguments);
```

Comment: I removed your personal email from the post - I didn't want you to get spammed.

Answer (score 12):

Unfortunately you cannot pass values to different constructors from the calling code.  In other words this will not work:

```
Foo foo = new Foo(arg1):base(arg2)
```

What you can do however is set up the constructors in `Foo` to do this for you.  Try something like this:

```
class FooBase
{
    public FooBase(Arg2 arg2)
    {
        // constructor stuff
    }
}

class Foo : FooBase
{
    public Foo(Arg1 arg1, Arg2 arg2)
        : base(arg2)
    {
        // constructor stuff
    }
}
```

Then you would invoke the constructor like this:

```
Foo foo = new Foo(arg1, arg2)
```

and the Foo constructor will route `arg2` to the base constructor for you.